# Canon EOS 6D/5D - Lightroom - Flickr - Exifdata missing

Tags: metadata, canon-5d-mark-ii, canon-6d, lightroom-5, flickr

I´m using Flickr for my Concertphotos. Please have a look: https://www.flickr.com/photos/50024469@N03/sets.

My problem is I can´t see which camera I have used, or the basic Exifs (apparture, shutter and ISO). Strange thing, because I used to see all of this on some other cameras I used before. Can anyone tell me where the "fault" presets might be? Thanks.

Data

Cameras: Canon EOS 6D and 5D markII
Program: Lightroom 5.7
Flickr

Comment: Please clarify your workflow and how do you upload the images in Flickr

Comment: And check what are your settings when you export from LR: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-hmbRT4iQTEk/VLzfcu98aEI/AAAAAAAAIeQ/Cm4E-zFpKgE/w419-h150-no/lr_meta.png

Comment: Export settings it was, Romeo Ninov:)

Comment: Will add it as answer to have it for community :)

Answer (score 7):

As from discussion with Per Olso Norway this can happen because of few reasons

- Setting in the export in LR (see image below)

[image]

- Software, used to upload image strip EXIF information. Original Flickr Uploadr do not do it
- Some other software in the workflow (xnview for example:
  Tools->Metadata->Clear)